# SqlDataReader Error: there is not converion between <null> and 'decimal'

Tags: c#

I'm working on a C# Desktop App and have a quetion about how to retrieve a value from a database using SqlDataReader.
When the value is a varchar in the table I save that value in an entity using this:

```
if (dr.HasRows){
    while (dr.Read()){
    Empleado dato = new Empleado();
    dato.DUIEmp = dr.IsDBNull(0) ? "No Info" : dr.GetString(0);
    ...
```

but I don't know how to retrive a decimal value from the database, for the time being I' using this but doesn't work:

```
dato.Salario = dr.IsDBNull(4) ? (decimal?)null : Convert.ToDecimal(dr.GetDecimal(4));
```

And also have the same problem with the Date value

```
dato.FechaIngreso = dr.IsDBNull(6) ? "No Info" : dr.GetDateTime(6);
```

Could you please help me and tell me how am I suposse to retrieve those type of data using SqlDatareader please?

Comment: to accommodate unassigned values in your data container use nullable fields: `decimal?`, `DateTime?`, `int?` etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, `decimal` and `DateTime` are not nullable. So, in the class where you have `Salario` and `FechaIngreso` properties declared, make those nullable;

```
decimal? Salario {get;set;}
DateTime? FechaIngreso {get;set;}
```

Comment: Thank you. I did the decimal? Salario {get;set;} change and this worked fine for me:  dato.Salario = dr.IsDBNull(4) ? (decimal?)null : Convert.ToDecimal(dr.GetDecimal(4));  but why it doesn't work  in strings for example: public string? name ?  I got the error Error 1 The type 'string' must be a non-nullable value type in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'System.Nullable<T>' ... BTW I'm saving records of data(a lot of Empleado Entities) into a IEnumerable type

Comment: `string` is already a nullable type. no need to use `string?`

Answer (score 1):

If the class `Empleado` has the `Salario` attribute declared as Decimal (not nullable decimal) then you should retrieve your value assigning a default value in case of null (like you are doing with the string field)

```
dato.Salario = dr.IsDBNull(4) ? default(decimal) : dr.GetDecimal(4);
```

Note also that calling GetDecimal doesn't require also the Convert.ToDecimal

So, if you have other datetypes then you could use the same approach,

```
dato.FechaIngreso = dr.IsDBNull(6) ? default(DateTime) : dr.GetDateTime(6);
```

Comment: excelente. )m worked just fine but what about when there are other types of data involved like DateTime, double, float? could I use always the 0m or should I use another expression i.e 0f(float), 0d(Datetime)...?

Comment: No, you need to use the appropriate type. Or better the default value for that type. Answer updated

Answer (score 0):

If your class is already:

```
decimal? Salario {get;set;}
DateTime? FechaIngreso {get;set;}
```

This way:

```
null as decimal?
```